# jQuery check cookie every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to check if a cookies exist every second, and change the display style for a image button. I have changed the display style to **none** through OnClientClick, and the click will trigger a ashx download to send back a test txt file with cookies "downloaded" to be true (I had make sure the cookie exist). However, the jQuery doesn't seem to be checking or looping, can someone check for me what's wrong with the code? Thanks!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataPull.aspx.cs" Inherits="DataPullForDemandPlanning.DataPull" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Data Pull For Demanding Planning</title>
    <style>
        .changeVisible{
            display: inherit;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function changeVisibility(stat) {
            var element = document.getElementById('ibtnPullData');
            if (stat == 'none')
                element.style.display = 'none';
            else
                element.style.display = 'inherit';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border-bottom-color: #990000; height: 30px; border-bottom-style: solid" valign="top">
                    <h2>Data Pull For Demand Planning</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Logged in as: <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="width: 60%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40px">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnPullData" runat="server" CssClass="changeVisible" ImageUrl="~/Images/ExcelLogo.gif" OnClick="ibtnPullData_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:changeVisibility('none');" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: auto">
                    Click Here to start data pull. The process may take up to 1 minute.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.removeCookie('downloaded', { path: '/' });

            jQuery.fn.timer = function () {
                var value = $.cookie('downloaded');
                if (value == 'true') {
                    changeVisibility('inherit');
                    $.removeCookie('downloaded', { path: '/' });
                }
            }

            window.setInterval(function () {
                $("changeVisible").timer();
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you load the page with cookies, the cookies stay, unless the page is reloaded or something, so either reload the page every second and check for the cookies or something...

Comment: If the cookie is being set from Javascript, you might as well use localStorage. With that you can listen for change events and react accordingly.

Comment: On the other hand, if the cookie is being set by server, then you are relying on Javascript validation only to display that image - which is not reliable. For instance, someone can still inspect the elements on the page and see the image.

Comment: @NisargShah the idea is while the file is being downloaded, the end-user will not be able to click on it. Yes the cookie is sent by server, but is there any thing wrong in my code that cause it unable to find the cookie and change back the display style?

Comment: `$("changeVisible")` should be `$(".changeVisible")`. But I'm not sure why you made this a jQuery widget, since it doesn't do anything with the element you call it on.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not even entirely sure if this is the right way to go. Do you have other recommendation? I am simply trying to change the image button's display style when the response sent back the cookies "downloaded".

Comment: Just define a normal function: `function timer() { ... }` then `setInterval(timer, 1000);`

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed answer if possible? I know very little about javascript....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer to a fully working version.

Thanks to @Barmar, I was able to easily achieve my goal with JavaScript only. Here is my code.

```
function changeVisibility(stat) {
    deleteCookie('downloaded');
    var element = document.getElementById('ibtnPullData');
    if (stat == 'none')
        element.style.display = 'none';
    else
        element.style.display = 'inherit';
}

var tim = setInterval(chechCookie, 1000);
function chechCookie() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("downloaded");

    if (myCookie != null) {
        changeVisibility('inherit');
    }
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
            end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```